# Display metadata with specific style on wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, metadata

I'm going to try to explain this the best way I can. I scrapped my other idea with the group because I couldn't get it to display. I'm new to php, so any help is appreciated.

So far, I have this in functions.php

```
function gallery_links_get_meta( $value ) {
    global $post;

    $field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $value, true );
    if ( ! empty( $field ) ) {
        return is_array( $field ) ? stripslashes_deep( $field ) : stripslashes( wp_kses_decode_entities( $field ) );
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function gallery_links_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'gallery_links-gallery-links',
        __( 'Gallery Links', 'gallery_links' ),
        'gallery_links_html',
        'post',
        'side',
        'core'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'gallery_links_add_meta_box' );

function gallery_links_html( $post) {
    wp_nonce_field( '_gallery_links_nonce', 'gallery_links_nonce' ); ?>

    <p>List gallery links as well as text.</p>

    <p>
        <label for="gallery_links_gallery_link_text"><?php _e( 'Gallery Link Text', 'gallery_links' ); ?></label><br>
        <input type="text" name="gallery_links_gallery_link_text" id="gallery_links_gallery_link_text" value="<?php echo gallery_links_get_meta( 'gallery_links_gallery_link_text' ); ?>">
    </p>    <p>
        <label for="gallery_links_gallery_link"><?php _e( 'Gallery Link', 'gallery_links' ); ?></label><br>
        <input type="text" name="gallery_links_gallery_link" id="gallery_links_gallery_link" value="<?php echo gallery_links_get_meta( 'gallery_links_gallery_link' ); ?>">
    </p><?php
}

function gallery_links_save( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['gallery_links_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['gallery_links_nonce'], '_gallery_links_nonce' ) ) return;
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;

    if ( isset( $_POST['gallery_links_gallery_link_text'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'gallery_links_gallery_link_text', esc_attr( $_POST['gallery_links_gallery_link_text'] ) );
    if ( isset( $_POST['gallery_links_gallery_link'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'gallery_links_gallery_link', esc_attr( $_POST['gallery_links_gallery_link'] ) );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'gallery_links_save' );

/*
    Usage: gallery_links_get_meta( 'gallery_links_gallery_link_text' )
    Usage: gallery_links_get_meta( 'gallery_links_gallery_link' )
*/
```

And I want to display the data like this on a post:

I need a `<?php if` thing here to only show the css if the post has the metadata filled out.

```
<div id="gallink">
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'gallery_links_gallery_link', true); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'gallery_links_gallery_link_text', true); ?></a>
</div>
```

But I don't want the "gallink" to show up if the metadata hasn't been filled in.

Also if I wanted to do multiple links, I would like it to go the same way but I think I might need another `<?php if` in case they don't fill in all of the fields. Like so:

```
<div id="gallink">
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'gallery_links_gallery_link', true); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'gallery_links_gallery_link_text', true); ?></a>
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'gallery_links_gallery_link2', true); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'gallery_links_gallery_link_text2', true); ?></a>
</div>
```

If they did not fill in the second set of metadata, I don't want it to show that one, but only show the first.

Maybe I need to add something else in the functions page to style it instead of doing it on the page?

I hope this makes sense. I can try to explain it better if needed and any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function to determine whether anything is in the meta element you are retrieving.

```
<?php
    $gallery_link_1 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'gallery_links_gallery_link', true);
    $gallery_link_1_text = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'gallery_links_gallery_link_text', true);
    $gallery_link_2 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'gallery_links_gallery_link2', true);
    $gallery_link_2_text = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'gallery_links_gallery_link_text2', true);
if (!empty($gallery_link_1_text) || !empty($gallery_link_2_text)) {
?>
<div id="gallink">
    <?php
        if (!empty($gallery_link_1) && !empty($gallery_link_1_text)) {
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $gallery_link_1; ?>"><?php echo $gallery_link_1_text; ?></a>
    <?php 
        } 
        if (!empty($gallery_link_2) && !empty($gallery_link_2_text)) {
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $gallery_link_2; ?>"><?php echo $gallery_link_2_text; ?></a>
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: technically, this would still show the empty `<div id="gallink"></div>` tag on the page. You should move that conditional logic before the `<div>` tag.

Comment: Took your advice - modified

Comment: Do I need to add anything to this code because when I add it into my theme I keep getting syntax errors. Again, I am so new to php so it's probably something on my end. Here's the template with your code in it where I would like it to go: http://freetexthost.com/woc3va5x4i  Thank you for the help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: No, my fault - Forgot an opening <?php tag right at the end. It should work now.

Comment: You are my hero, haha. Thank you! This has been the biggest help!